# Capture and run result_scan using query_id in Snowflake Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to run Describe table and running RESULT_SCAN on the query id of the describe table query.

Procedure:

```
var qry = ` describe table TEST_TABLE `;
var qry_rslt = snowflake.execute({sqlText: qry});
var qry_id= qry_rslt.getQueryId();

var qry2 = ` select * from table(result_scan('`+qry_id+`')) `
snowflake.execute({sqlText: qry2});
```

The procedure is returning Null and not running the SQL. On manually running the result scan query it says statement not found.

ANy idea how to read describe result.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually reading the results of the second query. It's running it but not collecting the results. This will collect the first column only of the result set:

```
create or replace procedure test()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

var qry = ` describe table TEST_TABLE `;
var qry_rslt = snowflake.execute({sqlText: qry});
var qry_id= qry_rslt.getQueryId();

var qry2 = ` select * from table(result_scan('${qry_id}')) `;
rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: qry2});

var out = "";
var i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    if (i++ > 0) out += ",";
    out += rs.getColumnValue(1);
}

return out;

$$;

call test();
```

Are you looking to get the entire DDL in one statement? If so you can run `get_ddl` and then read just the first row, first column. It will have the DDL for the entire table. If you want it as a table, you'll need to read the rows and columns to do what needs to be done with them.